# What does the Mexican term "predialazo" refer to?

Tags: palabras-raras, definiciones, méxico

There's a word whose definition has been requested on Wiktionary (perhaps by me but I can't remember) that seems to be [mostly used in Mexico if you Google for it](http://www.google.com.au/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Representantes%20de%2056%20colonias%20conformaron%20un%20frente%20com%C3%BAn%20para%20luchar%20en%20contra%20del%20predialazo,%20que%20en%20algunas%20zonas%20de%20la%20ciudad%20fue%20de%20hasta%20mil%20924%20por%20ciento.#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&safe=off&source=hp&q=%20predialazo%20&pbx=1&oq=%20predialazo%20&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=200911l200911l8l201089l1l0l1l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=ff0403f565a41028&biw=853&bih=447):

> `predialazo`

But it's not in the DRAE, Larousse Gran Diccionario, Google Translate, Wikipedia, etc. In the Wiktionary request this example with context is given:

> Representantes de 56 colonias conformaron un frente común para luchar en contra del **predialazo**, que en algunas zonas de la ciudad fue de hasta mil 924 por ciento.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No es un término exclusivamente mexicano; en Colombia también es un término usado: ver [este artículo](http://www.eluniversal.com.co/opinion/columnas/el-predialazo) del periódico *El Universal*, de Cartagena, titulado precisamente *El predialazo*.

Predialazo es, literalmente, un "golpe dado con el predial". Cuando un gobierno local decide hacer un ajuste desmedido al impuesto predial (o impuesto a la renta), entonces se habla de un "predialazo" pues figurativamente el valor exageradamente elevado a pagar por este impuesto representa un golpe a (los bolsillos de) los habitantes.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've reached my vote limit for today but I fully intend to +1 this answer when I can. For some reason I didn't spot the *-azo* suffix on this word even though it's one of my favourites.

Comment: @hippietrail: and I've reached the rep. cap today, so it's also better for me if you up-vote tomorrow ;-)

Comment: Oh yes I've crossed the cap too! (-: